# Python Selenium download MP4 where ACCESS PERMISSION (login) required

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, download, mp4

**TASK: Download a mp4 from a login-required link**

This login-required link means:

- If I paste the link on a new tab (in the same window on Google Chrome), it works! As long as it has been logged in.
- But if I use a new incognito window to open it, error message shown as follows:

> This page isn’t working
> If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
> HTTP ERROR 401

**Problem**

- Selenium chromedriver will prompt a new window and paste the MP4 link there, (same as pasting the link in incognito mode because no login being done in the new window)

Thus, in this case, we're not able to download things, as login required to access the content

**QUESTION:**
so, how do I ask python selenium chromedriver to **download the mp4 in the same window** (in order to access the content)?

Thanks You for helping me! I have been searching through online trying this out for days.

Answer (score 0):

#### Attempts:

1. 

Normally, I would use "requests" to do the following code snippets, but in this case we need to sign in:

```
with open(FileDB+ str(a)+ "." + str(lesson_name) +'.mp4', 'wb') as file:
    #,encoding="utf-8"
    file.write(video_response.mp4)
```

2. 

Then I tried out ways to plug in the username and password, which are incorrect:

Most likely, the login process simply can't be get through by using this way (As shown above, we have tried out to use a incognito window to open the link, and error msg HTTP ERROR 401 displayed, where we simply don't have places to give the sign-in details)

```
username = XYZ
password = XYZ

        video_response = requests.get(link, auth=(username, password), allow_redirects=True)

        with open(FileDB+ str(a)+ "." + str(lesson_name) +'.mp4', 'wb') as file:
            #,encoding="utf-8"
            file.write(video_response.mp4)
```

3. 

I also tried to use urllib, which apparently can't get through the login process by the following code:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, 'video.mp4')
```

4. 

I have also tried to use `crtl + t` to open a new tab manually and download it, but I wonder if there's other way out in addition to this manual way.

Thank you very much in advance for helping me solve this out!

The System used:
Spyder Python 3.7
ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87
Selenium